# remember-me redirects to "/" instead of the requested url

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a problem using success handler with remember-me. I need to perform some functions and set some session variables after a user logs-in. So I wrote this logic in Authentication success handler of remember-me.

Now when I am trying to access a deep link, like http://mySite.com/about.com it is being redirected to the root "/".

I referred to this thread [remember-me and authentication-success-handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575860/remember-me-and-authentication-success-handler) as my problem is exactly the same.

Currently I am using two different success handlers, one for form-login and the other for remember-me beacuase Luke pointed out that using SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler for remember-me isn't a good idea. So now my form-login uses a success handler which extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and my remember-me implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler. In order to get the originally requested url after closing and opening the browser I am not providing any redirect or a forward in the remember-me success hanlder as Luke suggested. But this isn't working. It is not redirecting or no content is returned from the server. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an `ExceptionTranslationFilter` ? You will need this to store the original request when an 'AuthenticationException' is thrown:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html