# WAS j_security_check with Spring security

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

How to disable remember_me feature when you are using Websphere provided j_security_check form based implementation?

Comment: You don't have to enable it to begin with. Also the container's `j_security_check` has nothing to do with Spring Security so I don't see how remember-me is be connected. You'll need to explain in more details what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Luke I guess my issue is more with cookies and session. I want every instance of browser for the same logged in user to be independent of each-other (Meaning whatever the logged in user sets in session in First browser window, shouldn't be accessible if user logs back in using new browser window.

Comment: That should happen anyway. You can't share a session between different browsers (different windows may share the same session though). Perhaps you're confusing remember-me with session cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `<remember-me>` tag from security configuration of spring. 
or in your login.jsp don't provide value for _spring_security_remember_me

Comment: Hi Jigar, thanks for the reply. I was able to turn off remember with supplying a false for _spring_security_remember_me. Is there a way to disable cookies in Spring MVC? I am setting some info in session for the logged in user and if this user opens another browser window he/she shouldnt be able to see the values set in the first browser window

Comment: good to hear that solution worked. please accept answer if has helped. for disable multiple login from different browser or tab i have using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128134/can-i-manage-multiple-browser-tabs-with-spring-security/11358163#11358163

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. `j_security_check` is the servlet container's internal login implementation. Whether the login form contains a `_spring_security_remember_me` parameter or not shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: _spring_security_remeber_me parameter is being used by spring security to check weather user has requsted for remember me or not if yes then create cookie and read next time on request