# Spring Security 2 userdetail in one session

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm doing a web project. One of the requirements is be able to login 2 different user accounts in one browser.

For example, if i have www.myproject.com/member logged in and i open a new tab and say I logged in again this time in the admin www.myproject.com/admin. Now if i try to access some of my user functions say, www.myproject.com/member/user-detail, I'm getting access denied response. I understand why because spring security only saves 1 user detail at a time. What I want is multiple accounts with different roles logged-in in a single browser.

Now do you know any work around on how to accomplish this?

Edited:

I want to be able to login on multiple browser tabs as long as the users logged-in have different roles.

Comment: open a new private window ;)

Comment: Seriously how is that a work around?

Comment: The question is : How will you handle which request belongs to which user? You have to write a full custom implementation. I think this is a very bad idea. This will no more work by example: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();  Why such a requirement?

Comment: Yes I know it will not work as I've tried. Well honestly i don't know that's why I'm asking here. But I think it's possible though. A perfect example is Gmail where you can log in 2 different accounts in 1 browser. So i supposed there's a work around here.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you see of one tab logging out another is normal for sites that have the security token stored in a single cookie. This is due to the spring security cookie being stored by domain name and login path (something like `www.myproject.com/login`).

To view this use the Chrome debugger or Firebug to view the cookies of the application.

Most web applications behave like this, take for example gmail up until not so long ago, it had the exact same behavior: logging in in one tab logged out a different user on a different tab.

This was changed in gmail recently, meaning they no longer store the security token in a single cookie like spring security.  It's unlikely they expose the security token in Javascript, it should still be in a HttpOnly cookie. Probably in each request a request header is filled which user to consider.

So it's possible to have different logins per tab in web applications, but spring security 
does not currently support it out of the box. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128134/can-i-manage-multiple-browser-tabs-with-spring-security) for some ideas of how to implement it.

Comment: I read this thread, it's similar to my problem. [link] (http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/110030-how-to-enable-multiple-user-logins-on-multiple-browser-tabs-or-instances). I haven't tried spring webflow so I tried to do a little reading on the docu but I couldn't see how can I solve my problem using it.